# Autogenerate Typescript Types for Cypress Custom Commands

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, e2e-testing

Suppose I have a **signup()** custom command for Cypress and I am using Typescript. To get types to work I have to declare my function, provide the function to Cypress, and provide the types to Cypress. Notice the repetition of **signup** in the snippet below.

```js
// in cypress/support/index.ts
// load type definitions that come with Cypress module
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import { signup } from "@cy/support/auth";

export {};

declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace Cypress {
        interface Chainable {
            signup: typeof signup;
        }
    }
}

Cypress.Commands.add("signup", signup);
```

Could this repetition be avoided with some fancy Typescript or a generator?

Something like **Cypress.Commands.add(signup);** might be nice, then the interface is created automatically (optionally provide string to override function name).